# dynamic web project cannot run

Tags: servlets, java-server

I created a dynamic web project, then added to the server already, (see screenshot) but I can't get it run. 
The server is running, if I type in `localhost:8080/` I do see the Apache homepage, but `localhost:8080/testDynProj/` yields nothing.
What am I missing? 
Thanks[image]

Comment: I right-click on Tomcat server (in the Servers view), then click Add And Remove, then select the project. Then restart the server. Tks

Comment: no no no! Just follow @madhairsilence answer below

Comment: tks MaVRoscy, definitely works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

1. Right Click the Project and Give **Run As -> Run on Server**
2. Check the web.xml. Check the tag

   ```
   <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>
       <!-- Your Start File -->
   </welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   ```
3. Expand the Project and Right Click the index page (any page which is the entry point for you app) and **Run as-> Run on Server**.

Comment: Great, when I put this into the web.xml, it works. Thanks a lot. Btw, any good tutorial on servlet you know of? I follow http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html but it seems there are so many exceptions they don't catch.
  `<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>hello</welcome-file>
    
  </welcome-file-list>`

Comment: I dont know a particular site. Google. Take different tutorials and try to understand the way they exhibit the tech. Why I was learning Struts and Spring, It took 7 different tutorials for me to understand things fully!